# Toolbar and statusbar overlap

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I've updated my app to use the new android design library recently, based on the awesome [cheesesquare example](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) by Chris Banes. It works perfectly, except for on android 5.0.2 devices, where the actionbar gets drawn behind de statusbar as reported in this thread as well:
https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/pull/14

This is my MainActivity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <nl.meetmijntijd.mmt.ui.controls.ControllableAppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/home_fragment_header_image_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/radial_gradient_grey"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/header_image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="130dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/main_cta_button"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                        android:elevation="3dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/app_white"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </nl.meetmijntijd.mmt.ui.controls.ControllableAppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
                app:layout_behavior="come.namespace.FixedScrollingViewBehavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_activity_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/app_background_light"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            tools:context=".MainActivity"
            tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

How can i resolve his issue? This big issue here is that i can't simply remove fitSystemWindows because i'm using a backdrop image in the expandable toolbar, and that needs to be drawn behind the statusbar.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems like you and I solved it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" <! -- Remove it -->
>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <nl.meetmijntijd.mmt.ui.controls.ControllableAppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/home_fragment_header_image_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/radial_gradient_grey"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/header_image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="130dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/main_cta_button"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                        android:elevation="3dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/app_white"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </nl.meetmijntijd.mmt.ui.controls.ControllableAppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
                app:layout_behavior="come.namespace.FixedScrollingViewBehavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_activity_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/app_background_light"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            tools:context=".MainActivity"
            tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I hope it help you

Thanks.